# HTTP Redirect from www.mydomain.com to my amazon ec2 account (instance)?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

I have a domain, that is registered at a service provider but my site (wordpress blog) is hosted in a shared account with a friend in another other host service. I want to become seperate from this friend because I'm tired of boring him with my blog downtimes. Now, my problem is that I signed up to Amazon EC2 service and I created a instance (a virtual machine) to host my wordpress blog and now I'd like to redirect mydomain.com to this instance at Amazon EC2 and I don't know how to proceed in order to achieve that. The instance at Amazon EC2 is up and running (it's a 64bit linux machine) but I couldn't redirect mydomain.com to this instance at my host service webpanel. Could someone help me please???

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign an Elastic IP address to you're EC2 instance. Once you have done this you should use your service provider's DNS tools to create an **[A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)** record for your domain that points to the Elastic IP address.

EDIT

Once you have the A record for your domain pointing to the elastic IP address if you want your domain to go directly  to your blog, then you need to set the `DocumentRoot` for your webserver to point to the directory containing your blog e.g.

If your blog is located in /var/www/worldpress then you would have a

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/worldpress
```

in your apache configuration file.

Comment: Ok! I've done that! I have an Elastic IP address assigned to my EC2 instance but my blog something like that 10.10.200.30/wordpress/ and my DNS service provider (dreamhost) doesn't accept such address.

Comment: That's not the elastic IP address that's the private address of the instance. Click on Elastic IPs below Network Security on the left the Elastic IP will then be listed in the main pane on the right.

Comment: you need to set the A record for your domain to pint to 50... then access it via http://your.domain.tld/worldpress.